# Excepción en el formateo de un dato traído desde MSSQL en C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mssql

Estimadxs, tengo un inconveniente a la hora de traer dos datos de una tabla de `MSSQL`. La tabla contiene dos campos que quiero traer: `CC_PreFijo` y `CC_Nro`. Estos datos en la tabla, como adjunto en la siguiente imagen, son de tipo INT el primero y de tipo BIGINT el segundo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo hago es que mediante un `DataGridView` al seleccionar un item del mismo, realizo una consulta a la tabla preguntando por esos valores (y otros también) pero la consulta me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'
```

Y me remarca esta línea:

```
int prefijo = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["prefijo"]?.ToString());
```

¿Cuál es mi error? Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a mi problema fue crear las variables de tipo `int` inicializadas en 0:

```
int prefijo = 0;
```

Y luego utilizo la propiedad `TryParse` del tipo de datos `int` tomando como dato de ingreso el valor de `sql` y **parseándolo** al valor de la variable:

```
int.TryParse(sqlDataReader["prefijo"].ToString(), out prefijo);
```

Answer (score 1):

El `BigInit` es igual a `Long` (64 bits) en C#, intenta algo de lo siguiente:

```cs
int prefijo = Convert.ToInt64(sqlDataReader["prefijo"]?.ToString());
```

Comment: Antes que nada, prefijo es de tipo INT no BIGINT. BIGINT es el número por lo que tu solución es errónea. De todas maneras, esa fue una de las cosas que probé y que no solucionó el problema